# Flutter - How to only display selected items in a List View

Tags: android, ios, variables, dart, flutter

I’ve been looking for a way to permanently store selected items from a list view into a different list view for **Flutter/Dart.**

This question **doesn’t** contain the full code, the project contains much more which can be viewed at: https://github.com/Jak3-02/myproject2

Any ideas on this will be greatly appreciated.

The main list view is located at `home_page.dart`

The second list view with saved items would be at `favourites_page.dart`

**This is the main list view in question:**

```
Widget _cryptoWidget() {
    return new Container(
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Flexible(
              child: new ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _currencies.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  final int i = index ~/ 2;
                  final Crypto currency = _currencies[i];
                  final MaterialColor color = _colors[i % _colors.length];
                  if (index.isOdd) {
                    return new Divider();
                  }
                  return _getListItemUi(currency, color);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
      );
  }

  ListTile _getListItemUi(Crypto currency, MaterialColor color) {
    return new ListTile(
      leading: new Image.network("http://cryptoicons.co/32@2x/color/"+currency.symbol.toLowerCase()+"@2x.png"),
      title: new Text(currency.name,
          style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
      subtitle:
      _getSubtitleText(currency.price_usd, currency.percent_change_1h),
      isThreeLine: true,
      trailing: new IconButton(
        icon: new Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () async { Directory appDocDir = await         getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;
        var myFile = new File('$appDocPath/my_file.txt')
        ..writeAsStringSync('myVar: $_currencies');  
        print(myFile.absolute.path);
        }
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Your question a little bit unclear. Are you asking about how to store the actual data (which the word 'permanently' might indicate), or are you asking how to show data on two different pages with a shared state (i.e. setting favourite on the main page makes it so that when you go to favourites the item is shown there).

Comment: Your second point, but with the ability to close the app, and have the users favourite still appear when the app is reopened; so the item in question doesn’t have to be repeatedly selected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I apologize - this has turned into a bit of a wall of text =D. Hopefully it helps though!

In flutter, data is almost always pass down the so-called 'widget tree'. This is partly for performance, but also seems to be paradigm the developers preferred.

This means that if you have two different 'pages', each shown with the navigator, it is not generally simple to share state between them.

However, there is one exception - if you will always be getting to the 'favourites' page from the 'main' page, you can push a MaterialPageRoute that includes the data. That would be something like this - copied directly from the [flutter getting started codelab](https://flutter.io/get-started/codelab/):

```
final _saved = Set<WordPair>()

....

Navigator.of(context).push(
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) {
        // instead of whatever they're doing here, you'd
        // parse your data and pass it in to your page.
        final tiles = _saved.map(
          (pair) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(
                pair.asPascalCase,
                style: _biggerFont,
              ),
            );
          },
        );
        final divided = ListTile
          .divideTiles(
            context: context,
            tiles: tiles,
          )
          .toList();

        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Saved Suggestions'),
          ),
          body: ListView(children: divided),
        );
      },
    ),
  );
```

The caveat to this approach is that if you ever wanted to go directly to the 'favourites' page from anywhere that isn't your 'main' page, you couldn't.

If that's an issue, you actually need to be passing the information down from above. There are several ways of doing this - I'll explain each and provide some recommendations about them.

**1: The simple way**

The simplest would be to simply keep data (i.e. list of favourites or identifiers of favourites) in a stateful widget at the level of your navigator and to pass the information into your pages when you construct them. You'd then make an `of` function on your stateful widget (see [Scaffold's `of`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/9a4db21129bf59cb455a46049bbf9e1dcc962b1d/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart#L909) - it's a common pattern in flutter) and have a function to set the state of this widget (you'd be setting the list of favourites).

There are a few issues with this approach:

- you might have to pass the data down through several levels of widgets, which isn't great for code maintainablility
- each time you add a favourite, you're rebuilding *everything* under the stateful widget which has the potential to slow things down.

**2: Slightly more elegant, but not following a pattern yet**

The intermediate way of doing this is to use an InheritedWidget along with a StatefulWidget. You have to place the inherited widget somewhere above your pages in the tree - above the navigator is your safest bet (or MaterialApp if your app just uses that as it has a Navigator within it).

If your inherited widget is in the widget tree, you can access it similarly to the statefulWidget from the last example - using an `of` method. Here's an example directly from the [InheritedWidget docs](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html):

```
class FrogColor extends InheritedWidget {
  const FrogColor({
    Key key,
    @required this.color,
    @required Widget child,
  }) : assert(color != null),
       assert(child != null),
       super(key: key, child: child);

  final Color color;

  static FrogColor of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(FrogColor);
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(FrogColor old) => color != old.color;
}
```

By using an InheritedWidget, your widget will rebuild whenever the inherited widget changes. However, that's not when the InheritedWidget's data changes - when it is actually replaced. The thing with InheritedData is that it is immutable (i.e. all members must be final), and that it still doesn't help with passing state back up the tree.

So you still need a StatefulWidget so that you can pass your favourites list up. This boils down to having an InheritedWidget built by the StatefulWidget, using `InheritedWidget.of` to read the data, and using `StatefulWidget.of` to set the state. See [this tutorial](https://flutterbyexample.com/set-up-inherited-widget-app-state/) for an example of how to wire this up.

The disadvantage is to this is that there's quite a lot of boilerplate.

**2.5: Let's simplify this a little =)**

Rather than having to deal with all of the wiring up each time for an inherited widget, you can use something to help, such as [the scoped_model plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/scoped_model). It allows you to simply write your model (inherited from scoped model). It's still using essentially the same underlying constructs though.

Here's an example directly from the scoped_model plugin:

```
// Start by creating a class that holds some view the app's state. In
// our example, we'll have a simple counter that starts at 0 can be 
// incremented.
//
// Note: It must extend from Model.  
class CounterModel extends Model {
  int _counter = 0;

  int get counter => _counter;

  void increment() {
    // First, increment the counter
    _counter++;

    // Then notify all the listeners.
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

// Create our App, which will provide the `CounterModel` to 
// all children that require it! 
class CounterApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // First, create a `ScopedModel` widget. This will provide 
    // the `model` to the children that request it. 
    return new ScopedModel<CounterModel>(
      model: new CounterModel(),
      child: new Column(children: [
        // Create a ScopedModelDescendant. This widget will get the
        // CounterModel from the nearest ScopedModel<CounterModel>. 
        // It will hand that model to our builder method, and rebuild 
        // any time the CounterModel changes (i.e. after we 
        // `notifyListeners` in the Model). 
        new ScopedModelDescendant<CounterModel>(
                builder: (context, child, model) => new Text(
                    model.counter.toString()),
              ),
        new Text("Another widget that doesn't depend on the CounterModel")
      ])
    );
  }
}
```

There are a few hacky things they do in the ScopedModel code, so that could be improved. But this is probably the simplest way code-wise of doing what you want.

**3: full-blown design pattern - BLoC**

Continuing the trajectory we've been following, the logical next option is to follow a design pattern that incorporates some of the elements we've been talking about but wraps it up with a bit more logic. One such pattern is BLoC (_B_usiness _Lo_gic _C_omponent), designed by google and with a fairly simple flutter implementation. Essentially using this, you're making a logic component that handles things - it could for instance actually handle retrieving the list of items as well as saving favourites. You use an InheritedWidget or ScopedModel to access the component.

I won't go into any more detail here as BLoC is better documented than I can explain, but you can take a look at [this flutter specific example](https://itnext.io/state-management-using-bloc-pattern-in-flutter-390d4056006f). The advantage to this approach is that your components are platform-independent, so you could use them in a different context such as AngularDart later.

The disadvantage of this is that you're still going to have to decide how to implement everything as it isn't opinionated about that, and there's still a decent amount of boilerplate needed.

**3.5: different design pattern - Redux**

A different paradigm you could adopt is Redux. I believe it originated with React, but there is a flutter port. It essentially treats everything as state, and then propagates state where it needs to. The advantage of this is that you can put a state adapter that does things like persist the data to a database, without changing the rest of yoru code.

Your best source of information about redux is [its flutter plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_redux). I personally don't like it very much as I feel it has too many rules about what you should and shouldn't do, and needs a lot of boilerplate, but to each their own.

**Persisting the data**

While the above options deal with how to pass the data around in a running instance, they don't really deal with how to persist it. For 2 and 2.5, you basically will have to put something in your logic that loads & saves the data somewhere - flutter has good support for SQLite with the [SQFlite](https://pub.dartlang.org/flutter/packages?q=sqflite) plugin, can use [SharedPreferences](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences), or you can use one of the Firebase databases (depending on how many favourites you're needing to save!).

If you're using BLoC, you'd essentially want to inject your storage mechanism into the component (to keep the component platform-independent), while with Redux you can use [redux_persist](https://github.com/Cretezy/redux_persist) to persist your stores.

---

Comment: Wow. This is an amazing explanation! Just one question, If I choose to load the app on the screen with the original list view (`home_page.dart`), can I scroll through to my favourites view(`favourites_page.dart`) using the navigator, then through to a third page, lets call it the settings page, and then back to the favourites page and still find all the saved information there? Or can it only be a two way system of `home_page.dart` to `favourites_page.dart`? Thank you

Comment: If you're using any of the more advanced ways, the data persists outside of the navigator and therefore you can use as many pages as you want. However, if you just go with the simple way I described very first (putting data in when you push the page) it will actually still work if you use it the way you described - every time you push a new page, it keeps the old one around. When you pop() back to the previous page, it's still the same one. What wouldn't work with the simple way of doing things is pushing the favourites, then pushing the settings, then pushing the favourites again.